# vim, typing the + register results in strange behavior

Tags: vim

I need to copy all the text from a script open in vim and I'm trying to use commands such as `gg"+yG` or `:%y +`, but whenever I press `+` even if I'm writing in the command line vim enters input mode and pastes a `l` and a new line wherever the cursor was.

I have other ways to do what I need, but why is this happening?

Comment: What does vim say if you type `:nmap +`?

Comment: When I type in the `+` it enters input mode an pastes a `1` and a newline, no other output

Comment: Could you post your `.vimrc`?

Comment: What if, in command line mode, you use `Ctrl-v` + `u` + `002b` (to type the plus sign without touching the `+` key)?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I don't have any `. vimrc` in my home, just a `.viminfo`

Comment: @Yoric by doing as you suggest I can have a `+` appear in the command line and execute whatever command I need

Comment: If you start as `vim -u NONE`, does it work?

Comment: no, it behaves the same strange way

Comment: If you can enter a `+` with Yorics trick, you can execute `:map +` and check the output.

Comment: for both `: map +` and `: nmap +` the output is that there is no such mapping (originally in chinese: `沒有這個 mapping 對應`)

Comment: Strange. Next: Go into insert mode and press `Ctrl-v` followed by `+`. This should normally only output a simple `+`. What does it for you?

Comment: It outputs this: `^[Ol`. which means the chracter I was seeing was a 'l' and not a '1'. (you can't see it, but there is also a newline/carriage return at the end).

Comment: Are you using the `+` key from the numeric keypad?

Comment: yes I was using the numeric pad, using the other `+` I can input it normally

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the comments:

You used the <kbd>+</kbd> on the keypad to enter the `+` character. For whatever reason, the terminal or keyboard driver or whatever sends the escape sequence `^[Ol` (thats `ESC` + `O`  + `l` [ upper case `o`, lower case `L`]). (It doesn't do that on my Ubuntu, gnome-terminal.)

Vim acts on this by leaving the command line, opening a new line and inserting the lower case `L`.

If you can't fix the terminal etc, you might work around this with the following mappings:

```
noremap <esc>Ol +
inoremap <esc>Ol +
```

and similar for the other numeric keypad keys.